# Matrix Properties Reference

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request

A lot of proofs I come across (working on stability of numerical methods) apply some property of a particular type of matrix. This includes, for example, the fact that the $L_{2}$ norm of a normal matrix is equivalent to its spectral radius, or that a unitary matrix, $U$, can be written as $U=e^{iH}$, where $H$ is a Hermitian matrix.

Does anyone know of a nice table or otherwise concise listing of matrix properties which one could refer to? I understand where (most) of these properties come from, but never manage to remember them all without some sort of prompting.

Comment: I've found [this book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=-c0NxJg4vHMC) to be quite a nice source of "quick facts" with lots of references in bibliography.

Comment: Have a look at the Matrix Cookbook: http://www.eattardo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/MatrixCookbook2012.pdf